# How to deselect part of a selected range in Excel 2013+

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2016

I'm using Excel 2013 and I'm having trouble deselecting part of a range that has been selected.

For example, if I select column C then Shift+click column E all the columns from C to E are selected.  Now say I want to deselect column D, leaving columns C and E selected.  I used to be able to Ctrl+click on the column and it would appear white, showing that it was deselected (the remaining selected columns would stay grey).

Now, however, when I Ctrl+click on column D instead of appearing white it gets darker.  The more I Ctrl+click the darker it gets.  According to the following Microsoft Support article this is a change in the design of Excel from 2013 onwards:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/help/2769340/cell-shading-continually-darkens-when-you-hold-down-ctrl-and-repeatedl

Their work-around is just to deselect everything and only select the columns I want.

Is there no way now that I can deselect part of a selected range?

Comment: @miroxlav: I found it hard to believe that Microsoft would have taken away such useful functionality without giving us an alternative.  However, the evidence seems to be stacking up: First that MS support article, now that previous question.

Comment: My knowledge of Excel says this thing was not taken away, but it was never present in Excel. I started using Excel in version Excel 95.

Comment: @miroxlav: Wow, I guess you're right.  I've been Googling to see if a past version of Excel ever had that functionality.  Apparently not.  I must have previously had CPearson's VBA macro (http://www.cpearson.com/excel/UnSelect.aspx) or a similar add-in installed without realising it.